# PCA and highly correlated Variables

Tags: correlation, pca

I simply wanna know what is the highest correlation accepted in PCA methodology.

Is 98% okay?

I'm selecting Macroeconomics variables for my study, and they are 105 variables.

Comment: It's ok, but if it's the best choice depends on your data. How many data points do you have? You can do cross validation, trying different correlation thresholds to see what works best.